# Is it possible to jailbreak an iPhone/iPod over a service like Teamviewer?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I was wondering if it was possible to jailbreak an iDevice (either iPhone of iPod) and possibly untether it, over a service similar to Teamviewer.
Would I be able to do it on Teamviewer without buying Teamviewer, is there a free and equivalent software that I could do it with other than Teamviewer?
And how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teamviewer is free to use for personal use. Just download and install/run. The only issue I see with doing this is that you may need to hold/press buttons on the iDevice in order to complete the jailbreak.

On teamviewer you should have no issue using the software though.